# Table Row Update/Remove Data in State(Array) and Toggle Add/Remove Class in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm having list of table and each row is clickable. Once I onclick the row need to add corresponding data to array. If I again click the same row need to remove the data from array. Likewise i need to add an toggle Active class for selected row.

```
const data = [
    {
        name: "Name1",
        foramt: "pdf",
        version: 0
    },
    {
        name: "Name2",
        foramt: "pdf",
        version: 0
    },
    {
        name: "Name3",
        foramt: "pdf",
        version: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Name4",
        foramt: "pdf",
        version: 5
    },
]
this.state = {
    active: false,
    activeIndex: null,
    selectedRow: []
}

<Table>
    data.map((item, index) => {
        const rowSelected = this.state.activeIndex === index ? "row-selected" : "";
     return 
        <TableRow className = {rowSelected} onClick={this.handleClick(item,index)}>
            <Cell>{item.name}</Cell>
            <Cell>{item.format}</Cell>
        </TableRow>
    })
</Table>

 handleClick = (item,index) => {
     const {activeIndex} = this.state;
     let array = []
    if(activeIndex !== index) {
        array.push(item);
    }
    this.setState({
      selectedRows: array
    })
  }
```

Comment: The `handleClick` does not handle the toggle event. You're just pushing the current selected index to selected rows and you're not really setting `activeIndex` on the state.

Answer (score 1):

**For the TableRow onCLick event:**

Change this:

```
onClick={this.handleClick(item,index)}
```

To

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(item, index)}
```

The first case will run immediately instead of waiting for the event to be called.

**And for the className**

Change this:

```
className={rowSelected}
```

To:

```
className={rowSelected ? "row-selected" : null}
```

In the first one when the `rowSelected === true` you'd get `className={true}` which doesn't really point to any class name.
In the second example though you'd get `className="selected"`